# Is this sentence correct/ does it fit in?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I'm writting a script for my presentation and I don't know if this sentance is correct. This sentance is for the second dia which is a summary of the parts that I want to talk about in my presentation. I'm concered about the useage of the word aspects and through out.
The sentance:
**(On the second dia) you can see what aspects/parts of  IOT I'm going to cover through out my 
 presentation.** 
The text of the 2nd dia:
-What is IOT ?​
-Exaples/ Histori​
-The impect of IOT.​
-The issues of IOT.​
-The future of IOT.​
-Challenges of IoT Software Development.​

​

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "aspects" and "throughout" (one word) are fine here.

Check for consistency as well as spelling: IoT or IOT, but not both.

I suspect that when you refer to a "dia" you mean a slide ("diapositive" in many European languages), not a diagram. Though of course there is room for overlap here :-)

Answer (score -1):

"On the second diagram you can see what aspects of IOT I'm going to cover in my presentation."

When you've finished your script, check it, double-check it. And then check it again. Correct spellings are: sentence, concerned, usage, throughout, history, examples, impact.